# The following query causes a MySQLSyntaxErrorException - what is wrong with my query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, exception

The following exception is thrown when ever I execute the following query

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-name, cpy-address, cpy-contact) VALUES('nauman','ahmad18',12)' at line 1

Query which is causing exception

```
  String query="insert into company(cpy-name, cpy-address, cpy-contact)VALUES(?,?,?)";
   Connection con=DataAccessLayer.getConnection();

   PreparedStatement stat=con.prepareStatement(query);
   stat.setString(1, cname);
   stat.setString(2, caddress);
   stat.setInt(3,x );
   int rowsAffected = stat.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Don't use '-' in a table/column identifier. It will drive you mad. And worse, may in special circumstances cause errors of which you would remain unaware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `-` in SQL queries. Escape the column names using `` ` `` back quote or back tick characters.

```
insert into company(`cpy-name`, `cpy-address`, `cpy-contact`)VALUES(?,?,?)
```

On another note, if the database is in your control, change to column names to use '_' rather '-'. Having illegal characters and quoting them is not a good practice.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

As @uday said you should change column name or use

> " ` "

Answer (score 2):

You can't use dash `-` symbol in SQL query in case of column name so that rename your column name or use Escape `` ` `` both side of column name and table name.